# How to use blank node in Datalog rules for GenericRuleReasoner?

Tags: jena, inference, jena-rules

I'm using GenericRuleReasoner to infer virtual fact in my ontology. GenericRuleReasoner takes inference rules as Datalog rule in input as explain in [jena inference support](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/). here is an example of a DatalogRule attached to a generic reasoner :

```
String rules = "[r1: (?e1 st:runningTask st:gic_eth0) -> (?e1 rdf:type st:dataFromEthernet2IP)]";
Reasoner reasoner = new GenericRuleReasoner(Rule.parseRules(rules));
reasoner.setDerivationLogging(true);
InfModel inf = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, rawData);
```

When i tested this code on my data, it worked fine and infered 2000 virtual facts. 
However, when I changed the Datalog rule in order to create blank nodes like this

```
String rules = "[r1: (?e1 st:runningTask st:gic_eth0) -> (_:p rdf:type st:dataFromEthernet2IP)]";
```

I get only on virtual fact inferred.

Is there a problem with my blank node representation in datalog rule for GenericRuleReasoner ?

Comment: Duplicated at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/29084/how-to-use-blank-node-in-datalog-rules-for-genericrulereasoner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a problem with my blank node representation in datalog rule for GenericRuleReasoner ?

Yes.  You don't use blank nodes like this in Jena rules.  The document that you linked to includes a [grammar for rules](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#RULEsyntax), and there's nothing in it that would permit something like `_:p` as a node.  The syntax for nodes in Jena rules is:

```
node      :=   uri-ref               // e.g. http://foo.com/eg
          or   prefix:localname      // e.g. rdf:type
          or   <uri-ref>             // e.g. <myscheme:myuri>
          or   ?varname              // variable
          or   'a literal'           // a plain string literal
          or   'lex'^^typeURI        // a typed literal, xsd:* type names support
```

If you want to create a new blank node, use the [`makeTemp(?x)` bulitin](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#RULEbuiltins) in the body of the rule to bind `?x` to a new blank node.  E.g.,

```
[r1: (?e1 st:runningTask st:gic_eth0), makeTemp(?p)
     ->
     (?p rdf:type st:dataFromEthernet2IP) ]
```